# How to use database index correctly when searching on geo field?

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

Suppose i have the following model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models

class Place(models.Model):
    location = gis_models.PointField(geography=True, srid=4326)
```

Later i am performing the search on those Places; my query is "fetch all places no further N meters from me":

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point


location = Point(1.0, 2.0)
distance = 20.0

queryset = queryset.annotate(distance=Distance("location", location)).filter(
        distance__lte=distance
    )
```

Is there any way using PostGIS to optimize those queries? For example, using indexes or something related.

Comment: Your question seems to be primarily about django, which you didn't tag.

Comment: My question is about PostGIS index, which, i think, extrapolates on any framework

Comment: Only if you want an answer in terms of SQL, which i assume you don't since you didn't show us any SQL.  How to get django to generate SQL is a django question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @fresser and @laurenz-albe helpfully suggested, the correct index is GIST index:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GistIndex

class Place:
    ...

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GistIndex(fields=["location"]),
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not look like SQL, and you did not tag a programming language, framework or ORM, so I'll give you an SQL answer.

To search for all `geometry`s that are less than 30 from a certain point, you would use

```
... WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, 'POINT(1 2)', 30)
```

The index to support that is

```
CREATE INDEX ON tab USING gist (geom);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Postgis funciton [ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) should use relevant bounding box indexes if existing.

To create such a [spatial index](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html), you can for example do the following:

```sql
CREATE INDEX unique_index_name ON table_name USING gist (geometry_column);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your data is in degrees (EPSG:4326) and you ask for everything with in 20 of a point. That 30 is in degrees and probably includes a large chunk (if not all) of your data so PostGIS is too smart to use your index.